# Ubuntu error: "make: *** [Makefile:947 build-gcc-12.2.0] Error 2 / make gcc failed! Aborting"

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, installation, gnu-make

I am trying to install software on Linux from GitLab using Ubuntu. I have cloned it successfully, but when executing the shell script file, I get the following error for which I have not found any answer:
"make: *** [Makefile:947 build-gcc-12.2.0] Error 2
make gcc failed! Aborting"

If it is relevant, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2, make 4.3 and gcc 11.3.0.

I am new to Linux and not very comfortable with it yet, so thank you in advance for your simple answers.

Comment: That error doesn't tell you anything.  It's an error telling you, "I ran the compiler command shown in the file `Makefile` line number `947`, but it failed".  If you want to know what the problem is you have to look earlier in the output and see what errors the compiler command printed.  In general, when programming the most important error messages are the FIRST ones, not the LAST ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed had a few mistakes that I have corrected (pip and pygraphviz not installed). But now, everything runs perfectly, I only have "ok", "successfully installed" or "requirement already satisfied" messages, but I ultimately end up with the same error message (after a few hours running). Do you have any clue where the problem could come from?

Comment: I just saw that when trying to install, a file 'install.txt' is created with thousands of lines but at the end there are a few lines like:
"xg++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1143: insn-emit.o] Error 1"
Could the explanation of the error be in that file?

Comment: As I said above, you'll have to find some other error because the one you quote above gives you no detail.  Make only knows that the thing it started failed, instead of succeeding, it has no way to know exactly how or why it failed.  For that you have to look for _error_ output (not normal output) from that thing.  And, once you find those messages you should edit your question and add them here, using cut and paste (not retyping by hand) and proper formatting as a code block.  Don't add them into comments because they can't be formatted properly.

Comment: If the message you get is `xg++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated ` then it means something or someone killed your compile.  Maybe the system ran out of memory and killed that process.  Exactly what was the command you used when invoking make?